# cropping x-ray image to remove background

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have many x-ray scans and need to crop the scanned object from its background noise.

The files are in .png format and I am planning to use OpenCV Python for this task. I have seen some works with FindContours() but unsure that thresholding will work for this case.

Before Image:

[image: Before Image]

After/Cropped Image:

[image: After/Cropped Image]

Any suggested solution/code is appreciated.

Comment: Independently, this is going to be difficult because the background is not uniform.  Do you, perhaps, have a blank image of the background?  You could probably subtract a background image here.  That would  make it much easier to find the regions that "aren't background".

Comment: @TimRoberts: Unfortunately the background also varies depending on the generator that is capturing the x-ray. Potentially I could classify images based on the generator and then try your idea.

Comment: The only other option I can think of is to compute a standard deviation for each row.  When the standard deviation spikes up, that's the start of your image.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV. It assumes you have the same excess border in all your images so that one can sort contours by area and skip the largest contour to get the second largest one.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread("table_xray.jpg")
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# median filter
filt = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 15)

# threshold the filtered image and invert
thresh = cv2.threshold(filt, 64, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
thresh = 255 - thresh

# find  contours and store index with area in list
cntrs_info = []
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
index=0
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    print(index, area)
    cntrs_info.append((index,area))
    index = index + 1

# sort contours by area
def takeSecond(elem):
    return elem[1]
cntrs_info.sort(key=takeSecond, reverse=True)

# get bounding box of second largest contour skipping large border
index_second = cntrs_info[1][0]
x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contours[index_second])
print(index_second,x,y,w,h)

# crop input image
results = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("table_xray_thresholded.png", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("table_xray_extracted.png", results)

cv2.imshow("THRESH", thresh)
cv2.imshow("RESULTS", results)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Filtered and Thresholded Image:

[image]

Cropped Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @fmw42 for your thoughtful response. I did run your solution on the same image (in JPEG and PNG format) using Jupyter (MACOS, python 3.9.2 ,cv2 4.5.1) and although the Threshold Image outcome is similar to yours, I get the full image instead of cropped image. My images have two different borders and I will upload an example of the second one too. Moreover, my kernel remains busy after running the code. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

This is another possible solution. It uses the **K-Channel** of your input image, once converted to the `CMYK` color-space. The `K` (or *Key*) channel has most of the information of the black color, so it should be useful for segmenting the input image. After that, you can apply a heavy morphological chain to produce a good mask of the object. After that, cropping the object is very straightforward. Let's see the code:

```
# Imports
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
imagePath = "D://opencvImages//"
inputImage = cv2.imread(imagePath+"jU6QA.jpg")

# Convert to float and divide by 255:
imgFloat = inputImage.astype(np.float) / 255.

# Calculate channel K:
kChannel = 1 - np.max(imgFloat, axis=2)

# Convert back to uint 8:
kChannel = (255*kChannel).astype(np.uint8)
```

The first bit of the program converts your image to the `CMYK` color-space and extracts the `K` channel. OpenCV has no direct conversion to this color-space, so a manual conversion is necessary. We need to be careful with the data types because there are `float` operations involved. The resulting image is this:

[image]

Pixels with black information are assigned an intensity close to `255`. Now, let's threshold this image to get a binary mask. The threshold level is fixed:

```
# Threshold the image with a fixed thresh level
thresholdLevel = 200
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(kChannel, thresholdLevel, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

This produces the following binary image:

[image]

Alright. We need to isolate the object, however we have both the lines of the background and the "frame" around the image. Let's get rid of the lines first. We will apply a morphological `Erosion`. Then, we will remove the frame `Flood-Filling` with black color at two locations: **upper left** and **bottom right** of the image. After that, we will apply a `Dilation` to restore the object's original size. I wrapped these OpenCV functions inside custom functions that save me the typing of a couple of lines - These helper functions are presented at the end of the post. This is the approach:

```
# Perform Small Erosion:
binaryImage = morphoOperation(binaryImage, 3, 5, "Erode")

# Flood-Fill at two locations: Top  left corner and  bottom right:
(imageHeight, imageWidth) = binaryImage.shape[:2]
floodPositions = [(0, 0),(imageWidth-1, imageHeight-1)]
binaryImage = floodFill(binaryImage, floodPositions, 0)

# Perform Small Dilate:
binaryImage = morphoOperation(binaryImage, 3, 5, "Dilate")
```

This is the result:

[image]

Nice. We can improve the mask by applying a second morphological chain, this time with more `iterations`. Let's apply a Dilation to try and join the "holes" of the object, followed with a Erosion to, once again, restore the object's original size:

```
# Perform Big Dilate:
binaryImage = morphoOperation(binaryImage, 3, 10, "Dilate")

# Perform Big Erode:
binaryImage = morphoOperation(binaryImage, 3, 10, "Erode")
```

This yields the following result:

[image]

The gaps inside the object have been filled. Now, let's retrieve the `contours` on this mask to find the object's contour. I've additionally included an `area filter`. The mask is pretty clean by this point, so maybe this filter is not too necessary. Once the contour is located, we can crop the object from the original image:

```
# Find the contours on the binary image:
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binaryImage, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# BGR image for drawing results:
binaryBGR = cv2.cvtColor(binaryImage, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# Look for the outer bounding boxes (no children):
for _, c in enumerate(contours):

    # Get blob area:
    currentArea = cv2.contourArea(c)

    # Set a min area value:
    minArea = 10000

    if minArea < currentArea:

        # Get the contour's bounding rectangle:
        boundRect = cv2.boundingRect(c)

        # Get the dimensions of the bounding rect:
        rectX = boundRect[0]
        rectY = boundRect[1]
        rectWidth = boundRect[2]
        rectHeight = boundRect[3]

        # Set bounding rect:
        color = (0, 255, 0)
        cv2.rectangle( binaryBGR, (int(rectX), int(rectY)),
                       (int(rectX + rectWidth), int(rectY + rectHeight)), color, 5 )

        cv2.imshow("Rects", binaryBGR)

        # Crop original input:
        currentCrop = inputImage[rectY:rectY + rectHeight, rectX:rectX + rectWidth]
        
        cv2.imshow("Cropped", currentCrop)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The last step produces the following two images. The first is the object enclosed by a rectangle, the second one is the actual crop:

[image]
[image]

I also tested the algorithm with your second image, these are the final results:

[image]
[image]

Wow. Somebody brought a gun to the airport? That's not OK. These are the helper functions used earlier. This first function performs the `morphological operations`:

```
def morphoOperation(binaryImage, kernelSize, opIterations, opString):
    # Get the structuring element:
    morphKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernelSize, kernelSize))
    # Perform Operation:
    if opString == "Dilate":
        op = cv2.MORPH_DILATE
    else:
        if opString == "Erode":
            op = cv2.MORPH_ERODE

    outImage = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryImage, op, morphKernel, None, None, opIterations,
                                   cv2.BORDER_REFLECT101)
    return outImage
```

The second function performs `Flood-Filling` given a list of seed-points:

```
def floodFill(binaryImage, positions, color):
    # Loop thru the positions list of tuples:
    for p in range(len(positions)):
        currentSeed = positions[p]
        x = int(currentSeed[0])
        y = int(currentSeed[1])
        # Apply flood-fill:
        cv2.floodFill(binaryImage, mask=None, seedPoint=(x, y), newVal=(color))

    return binaryImage
```